# How should I program an API 21 (only) application?

Tags: android

First of all , I am a beginner to android development and I know my question may sound stupid, but I believe it will help me understand some aspects of the SDK that are very confusing to me.

I am trying to (for fun) program an app , that will be only used on my phone for personal use. My phone is running 5.0.1, so I have no problems setting the min SDK to be 21.

What I am really confused about is the support libraries. In my application I am trying to implement things such as the DrawerLayout, RecyclerView, the default action bar etc. All the guides and information I have found so far point at using the support libraries to achieve most of these things, which is completely understandable since commercially nobody wants their app to be only availible on Lollipop and higher. 
However, since I am a special case and that's pretty much exactly what I want (because I presume it is easier to achieve) - to make a NON-BACKWARDS COMPATIBLE application, with some fancy stuff from lollipop. And here comes the confusion, most of these classes that are in the support libraries are not to be found outside of them. I thought there would be a RecyclerView class only availible for API21 applications , and if your sdk support is less than 21 then I would use the android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView instead.

Having said all that , how should I proceed with my application ?
Should I use support library classes in situations where I don't need backwards compatibility at all? Or is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach to this that doesn't allow me to use the new classes?

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: just because you use stuff from the support library does not mean you have to provide backwards compatibility, some items you need to use the support library for

Answer (score 0):

While some widgets and classes have its own version outside the support library (e.g. Fragment, introduced in API 11), others (like ViewPager, DrawerLayout) are part of the support library.

Comment: I could not find the RecyclerView outside the support library, are you sure about that ?

Comment: RecyclerView is only in the support library

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I believe Fragment is a better example. Edited.